# How can I change an element's text without changing its current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[image]

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "my url" + x,
    datatype: "html",
    success: function(data){
        //alert(x);
         //var Content = data;
         var sendId ;
         var data = $.parseJSON(data);
         var jsonArray = data.result;

        // var data2 = $.parseJSON(jsonArray);
         var jsonArray3 = jsonArray.oilFilter;
         $.each(jsonArray3,function(i1,js2){
             var proname = js2.productName;
             var mrp = js2.mrp;
             var deliveryStatus = js2.deliveryStatus;
             var oilid = js2.productId;
             $(".oilid").val(oilid);
             $(".deliveryStatusOil").html(deliveryStatus);
             $(".mrpoil").html(mrp);
             $(".oilprodetail").html(proname);


         });

    <label id="oilprodetail" class="oilprodetail"></label><br/>
    <label id="mrpoil" class="mrpoil"></label><br/>
    <a onClick="ajax_cross(this);" id="oilid" class="oilid" >View</a>
```

If you go through the code I am assigning values to label tag with id oilprodetail and mrpoil and i am doing the same thing to oilid as well, 
My requirement is to send oilid value to a tag and retain view there,
Please help? I am new to ajax..

[image]

In the above picture i need to do the right part of the pic that is view,,
but when i send the data it changes to left part of the pic like it changes from view to the value that is sent

Comment: Are you trying to `.append()` `html` to elements?

Comment: nope. I am trying to assign the value like we do it inline. but here its not inline

Comment: What do you mean by "assign the value like we do it inline"? Not certain what issue is?

Comment: What is purpose of `$(".oilid").val(oilid);`? `#oilid` is an `<a>` element

Comment: the a tag is outside the ajax code, so i have to use method to make it a link but i dont want to change the word view.

Comment: What is purpose of $(".oilid").val(oilid);? #oilid is an <a> element..... To read and write value to the html tag

Comment: @melwinpintoe Maybe you want `$(".oilid").attr('href', oilid);`? It's really hard to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: @melwinpintoe Maybe you can share what you want the HTML to look like after this code runs.

Comment: You can remove `$(".oilid").val(oilid);` from `javascript` if requirement is to not change text within element. Though should probably be `$(".oilid").html(oilid);` if you are trying to change `html`, or `.append()` if you want to append content adjacent to `"View"` word

Comment: sure i would do that,,

Comment: <a class="filter" href="#" onClick="ajax_loader('+js.oilid+');">'+js.oilType
               +'</a> in this case i have written the code inside the ajax result success part... in the above case the a tag is not in the ajax part

Comment: So you tell jQuery that you expect HTML (dataType), but misspell it (no capital T), then parse it as JSON and put it in a variable named jsonArray, which is neither of the two...

Comment: _"To read and write value to the html tag"_ to `href` attribute or `.innerHTML` of element? _"<a class="filter" href="#" onClick="ajax_loader('+js.oilid+');">'+js.oilType +'</a>"_ does not appear at Question?

Comment: @melwinpintoe In that HTML, the word "View" is gone. I thought you wanted it there.

Comment: you are correct i want it there.. but it goes off

Comment: @melwinpintoe When you decide what you want, I suggest that you ask for help as part of a new question.

Comment: The problem is to pass the id, I am able to get what i want but, I but its changing the content of it..

Comment: The content of what? Of the `a` element? That is what you said you wanted, no?

Comment: What is `ajax_cross`? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @trincot i am trying to call the function with ajax cross and pass the value

Comment: But you pass it `this`, which is not the value, but the element....

Comment: i have added the pic please have a look at it

Comment: How many elements you expect in the ajax returned array? If more than one, your current code will just overwrite in each iteration the same elements...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120926/discussion-between-melwinpintoe-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute to keep innerHTML of "a" tag. Like :

```
$(".oilid").attr('data-oilid',oilid);
```

Comment: This is probably better written `$(".oilid").data("oilid", oilid);`, but I see no indication that this is what the questioner is trying to do.

Comment: If you have right value in oilid then just use: $(".oilid").html(oilid);

Comment: But the word view changes to the value i send, I want it to show as view itself

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- You misspelled `datatype`,  which should be `dataType`;
- Even if correctly spelled, you then wrongly identify the data type as HTML: you really expect JSON, which is something different;
- Without the `dataType` property (which is your case), jQuery will guess the data type, and probably will guess it to be JSON. In that case, `$.parseJSON` will fail, because jQuery will already have decoded the JSON string and present the result as the `data` argument;
- You use the `.html(...)` method to set the content of some elements to some text. `html()` should only be used when the content really is HTML, but otherwise (which I think is your case), you should `.text(...)`;
- An `a` element does not have a `value` property, so calling `.val()` on it does not have the desired effect;
- You want to pass the `oilid` value to the `ajax_cross` function, but provide it `this`, which is an HTML element (the `a`), not the value.
- As you iterate the array, you are setting the content of the exact same elements in each iteration over and over again, which means only the last iteration determines what the content will be. You should put each text in the proper element, avoiding to overwrite the previous written value.
- The HTML you have shared, only has space for writing the result of the first array element to -- there should be similar elements for the second row, third row, etc.

To solve all this, you could get inspiration from this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "my url" + x,
    dataType: "json", // corrected spelling and type
    success: function(data){
        // Don't parse as JSON string any more, data alread is object;
        // Don't name your variable jsonArray, it is neither of those
        var result = data.result;
        var jsonArray3 = result.oilFilter;
        $.each(jsonArray3, function (i1, js2) {
            var proname = js2.productName;
            var mrp = js2.mrp;
            var deliveryStatus = js2.deliveryStatus;
            var oilid = js2.productId;
            // bind onclick handler with oilid argument bound to it:
            // use `get()` to select the next element of the same class:
            $(".oilid").get(i1).off('click').on('click', ajax_cross.bind(null, oilid));
            // use text(), not html()
            $(".deliveryStatusOil").get(i1).text(deliveryStatus);
            $(".mrpoil").get(i1).text(mrp);
            $(".oilprodetail").get(i1).text(proname);
        });
    }
});

<label id="oilprodetail" class="oilprodetail"></label><br/>
<label id="mrpoil" class="mrpoil"></label><br/>
<!-- remove onclick attribute, we bind the handler dynamically -->
<a id="oilid" class="oilid" >View</a>

<hr><!-- repeat elements for second row -->
<label id="oilprodetail" class="oilprodetail"></label><br/>
<label id="mrpoil" class="mrpoil"></label><br/>
<!-- remove onclick attribute, we bind the handler dynamically -->
<a id="oilid" class="oilid" >View</a>

<hr><!-- repeat elements for third row -->
<label id="oilprodetail" class="oilprodetail"></label><br/>
<label id="mrpoil" class="mrpoil"></label><br/>
<!-- remove onclick attribute, we bind the handler dynamically -->
<a id="oilid" class="oilid" >View</a>
```

The above is still not ideal, as you would better create the elements dynamically as you iterate through the Ajax results, so you would have just as many as you would need.

Comment: Okay sir i'll try to do that dynamically. so as to display what i want. Thank you very much for the help...

Comment: Please note the `.bind` that I have added in the code just now and had forgotten at first.